# How to return list from flux of mongodb returned value

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

anyone can you help me. am using spring boot application with reactive mongodb repository.
i want get a value as a list of ids.

```
List<String> userIds = assignJob();

public List<String> assignJob(){
    return userRepository.findAllByStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE)
            .map(userSchema -> {
                return getUserId(userSchema);
            });
}

private String getUserId(UserSchema userSchema){
    return userSchema.getId();
}
```

Repository

```
import com.colakins.measurementtools.persistence.enumeration.UserStatus;
import com.colakins.measurementtools.persistence.schema.UserSchema;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<UserSchema, String> {
    Mono<UserSchema> findOneByEmail(String email);

    Flux<UserSchema> findAllByStatus(UserStatus status);
}
```

userSchema

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document("users")
public class UserSchema {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting you results from `userRepository.findAllByStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE)`?

Comment: yes @varman . userRepository.findAllByStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE)  it reurns flux value but i want ids only with list

Comment: Can you try this `return userRepository.findAllByStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE).map(m -> m.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());`